# How do I insert and remove a div together with its contents on a link click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am new at using jQuery but I really want to include some common javascript functionality to my website. I have a div that presents a form to a user where by he/she can enter some information. What I would like to do is to display the div when required but hide it when it isn't required.

Here is the jQuery code I am using to select and remove the div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#newRequestCancel").click(function() {
            $("#newRequestForm").remove();
        });
</script>
```

and here is the html tag

```
 <h3 class="main-top">

                    <a href="#" id="new-request-make">New Product</a>
                </h3>
                <div id="newRequestForm" class="panel">
                    <form action="index.php" method="post">
                        <p><label>Title</label><span class="required">*</span></p>
                        <p><input type="text" /></p>
                        <p><label>Image</label><span class="required">*</span></p>
                        <p><input type="file" /></p>
                        <p><label>Description</label><span class="required">*</span></p>
                        <p><textarea></textarea></p>
                        <p><label>Preferred Price [KES]</label><span class="required">*</span></p>
                        <p><input type="number" /></p>
                        <p><label>County</label><span class="required">*</span></p>
                        <p><select><option disabled selected="selected">.: Select a County :.</option></select></p>
                        <p><label>Location</label><span class="required">*</span></p>
                        <p><input type="text" /></p>
                        <br/>
                        <p>Any field marked with an asterisk (<span class="required">*</span>) is required.</p>
                        <br/>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Make Request" /><span class="ibar"></span><a href="#" id="newRequestCancel">Cancel</a></p>
                        <br/>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

So if I click the **new product link** its supposed to insert the div and when I click the **cancel link** inside the div its supposed to remove it. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Masaba and welcome to the site.

You are looking for `.show()` and `.hide()` not `.remove()`.  Remove completely deletes the HTML so you can't show it again.

```
$("#newRequestCancel").click(function() {
        $("#newRequestForm").hide();
    });

$("#new-request-make").click(function() {
    $("#newRequestForm").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
         $('#new-request-make').click(function()
         {
              $('#newRequestform').show();
         });
          $("#newRequestCancel").click(function() {
              $("#newRequestForm").hide();
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery [**.show()**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [**.hide()**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

To show:

```
$("#new-request-make").click(function() {
    $("#newRequestForm").show();
});
```

To hide:

```
$("#newRequestCancel").click(function() {
    $("#newRequestForm").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#newRequestCancel").click(function() {
        $("#newRequestForm").hide();
    });

    $("#newRequestLoad").click(function() {
        $("#newRequestForm").show();
    });
</script>
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here, a beautiful present for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/eX3QK/

```
<div id="login">
    <a href="#"><p style="font-size:16px;">Hello</p></a>
    <div class="arrow_box">
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery is used, change html tag to whatever.

```
$("#login").click(function(e){
    $("#login div").css("visibility","visible");
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").click(function(e){
    $("#login div").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```